# SQLAlchemy: Why importing using relative or absolute paths returns different instance of object <Base class>

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following issue in a project that uses SQLAlchemy. I've put all the code after the question.

**If I use `from base import Base` in create_tables.py (as seen in the code below)**, the tables are not created.
**If I use `from persistence.base import Base` in create_tables.py**, the tables ARE created.

**Why does this happen? Why does using the absolute import path fix everything?**

I suspect that when I use `from base import Base` a new, clean Base class instance is used, so SQLAlchemy does not know of the child classes that inherit from Base and make up the tables. However, I don't understand why using the absolute import path (persistence.Base) actually solves the issue.

Another point to make is that I use absolute import paths in the *_api.py files as you can see below. How would using relative path imports and absolute path imports affect the outcome of this situation?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Project's structure:

```
src
--persistence
----create_tables.py
----base.py
----user
------user_api.py
----expenditure
------expenditure.py
----statement
------statement.py
```

Relevant code:

base.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

expenditure_api.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, ForeignKey, String, TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from persistence.base import Base

class Expenditure(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'expenditure'

    expenditure_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    expenditure_user_id = Column(ForeignKey('user.user_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    expenditure_issue_date = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    expenditure_payment_date = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    expenditure_receipt_id = Column(String(45))
    expenditure_statement_id = Column(ForeignKey('statement.statement_id'), index=True)
    expenditure_transaction_details = Column(String(255))
    expenditure_payment_num = Column(INTEGER)
    expenditure_total_payments = Column(INTEGER)
    expenditure_amount = Column(Float(asdecimal=True), nullable=False)
    expenditure_currency = Column(String(45), nullable=False)

    expenditure_statement = relationship('Statement')
    expenditure_user = relationship('User')
```

statement_api.py

```
# coding=utf-8

from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, ForeignKey, String, TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER

from persistence.base import Base

class Statement(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'statement'

    statement_id = Column(String(255), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    statement_from_date = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    statement_to_date = Column(TIMESTAMP)
```

user_api.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, ForeignKey, String, TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER

from persistence.base import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user_username = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    user_full_name = Column(String(255))
```

create_tables.py

```
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from persistence_config import sql_server_socket, database_name

from user.user_api import User
from expenditure.expenditure_api import Expenditure
from statement.statement_api import Statement

from base import Base

from create_logger import create_logger

logger = create_logger(__name__)

def create_tables(engine):

    # try:
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        logger.info(f"Tables created.")
    # except exc.DatabaseError as ex:
    #     logger.error(f"create_tables error: {ex}")
    # except:
    #     logger.exception("create_tables error.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from persistence_config import sql_server_socket, database_name
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    
    engine = create_engine(sql_server_socket + "/" + database_name, echo=True)
    create_tables(engine)
```

Comment: How do you run `create_tables.py` and from which directory? My memory is a bit hazy on the subject, but I don't think `from base import ...` is relative in Python3, but absolute, and so your guess would be right on the money; you end up with 2 different `Base` classes from different module instances. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3 is a good read.

Comment: I am running it as a script. As per my environment settings, sys.path is like this:

 ['D:\\projectRootDir\\\\src\\persistence', 'D:\\projectRootDir\\\\src', 'D:\\projectRootDir\\', ...]

Comment: Aye, your Python path is off, and so you are able to (absolute) import the same code twice as 2 separate modules. Read the linked Q/A, it covers your situation and has the solution to it (running scripts from within packages).